# What does REQUEST_TIME mean in PHP?

Tags: php

Is it the time when I click the send button on my HTML form, or the time when it arrives to the server?

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; ?>
```

Edit:

I have already read the manual, Googled other sources - including SO. The clearest definition I've found is still ambigous to me, as I don't know what the *start of the request* means exactly in the definition below.

> 'REQUEST_TIME'
>
> The timestamp of the **start of the request**. Available
>   since PHP 5.1.0.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

It could mean the moment when the request leaves the client, or the moment when it arrives to the server. It is not always the same, especially if the network speed is low and the latency is high.

Edit 2:

This is not a "just because" type of question. I need to maintain a food ordering service, and people with poor internet often have problems: sometimes they think we get the order when we don't, other times they think we don't get it when we do. So I've set an XHR timeout, to inform the user that the request took too much time so she should try again. But the timeout happens only on client side: the request still arrives to the server. So the server needs to know the time of the sending, not the receiving, so that it can be sure it's not a timed out request that should be discarded.

Comment: if there's a time difference between you and your server, then that will depend on you guys locations

Comment: [did you really read it online? if so, why are you asking this question? what did you not understand?](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: @Fred-ii- What time difference do you mean? Time zones? I don't know how is that related to this question. It's rather about internet speed and latency: if my request takes a minute to reach the server, the mentioned PHP variable's definition becomes important.

Comment: there is a difference. If your server resides in another timezone/country, then that too needs to be taken into account. If you have and for example, a client that places an order that needs to be in before a certain time yet your database (again, an example) restricts them from placing that order because of the time differences, then guess what? Think about it.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Yes, I have read it, like I said before. I'm asking this question, because the definiton is ambigous to me. The reason is simple: I don't know what is considered as the start of the request.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Time zone conversion is a real thing, but that's not an issue for me, I know how to do it. My question is about a certain PHP server variable i.e. the 'REQUEST_TIME'. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: It was just a thought and what I thought to be a valid one and should be taken into consideration. This also for future visitors to the question/answer who may not know about this.

Comment: However and as @Iwrestledabearonce. did ask and with the link to http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php clearly states *"'REQUEST_TIME' The timestamp of the start of the request. Available since PHP 5.1.0."*. I believe it speaks for itself.

Comment: on the other hand though, if you know php only runs on the server then the answer might be obvious

Comment: no, the server can never rely on any given header to exists.

Comment: *"Is it the time when I click the send button on my HTML form, or the time when it arrives to the server?"* - If you're recording this in either writing to a file and/or a database, then yes; it will record the time it was processed at the time the action was done. I think I answered the question here, yet we don't know what this is used for exactly so that is the best answer I can give. You'll need to edit your question as to the reason/nature for this, IMHO.